# fgets getting stuck indefinitely in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: c, linux, pipe, thread-safety

I have a system which consists of multiple threads. Each thread uses a common function called `RunCmd` to execute a shell command. Everything works okay, but once in a while one of the threads (always the Alerts thread) gets stuck inside the `RunCmd` function indefinitely. After adding some logging, it turns out that it gets stuck in the fgets call.

It is also worth noting that it does not matter what the shell command is, but it is getting stuck in the same place.

About the system:

- This is all running on an embedded Linux system with a TI chip
- All of these threads are running on a service - only one process (checked the ps aux command)

Weird observations:

- When observing the logs using journalctl, I see that for that service there seems to be different PIDs reported. Mostly it is the same PID (cross checked with ps aux), but some logs have different PIDs and these PIDs are not available in the ps aux list.

How can I further debug this? and trace logs or something else?
Are there any workarounds?

Here is the `runCmd` functions that gets stuck in that thread:

```c
bool runCmd(char const* command, char* response, size_t bufferSize) {
    FILE* pFile = popen(command, "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        return false;
    }
    if (NULL != response) {
        while (fgets(response, bufferSize, pFile) != NULL) {
            response = response + strlen(response);
        }
    }
    pclose(pFile);
    return true;
}
```

- Adding a mutex so only one thread is running a shell command - it just resulted in all the threads getting stuck as the Alerts thread was hogging the mutex and stuck in there
- Tried freads instead but the same output
- Tried using `select` to wait until the pipe was available before reading and timing out if took too long - but no difference

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please try to create a [mre] to show us. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Lastly please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Read the tag [tag:c] description: C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is a perfectly fine question, stop complaining

Comment: @Fredrik Since it's a question about thread-safety, ideally, it would show how it's doing the threading part. Now it only shows one function that  in itself is thread-safe as long as it's given a `command` and `response` buffer that will not be altered by another thread. Given that the function is all we see, my answer points out the bug in the function as the possible culprit.

Comment: The issue is fgets is NOT threadsafe. it shares a return buffer across all threads

Comment: @Ash Gupta, Post how `runCmd()` is called, a [mcve].

Comment: @Ash Gupta, What should happen when `bufferSize` is too small to read the lines of input?

Comment: @PepijnKramer What? I'm not sure what the standard says but it's marked as MT-Safe in Linux.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Did you perhaps think about the `explain_fgets` function (which is not thread-safe)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Then maybe I used the wrong source of info. The standard doesn't even seem to mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rest of the code that we can't see is thread-safe (and no other thread is changing the buffers that `command` and `response` points at), I see one bug and two possible causes for the hanging `fgets`.

- Bug: The program may fill the `response` buffer and then start to write out of bounds since you have no boundary check. The loop will tell `fgets` to read up to `bufferSize` characters every time even though you are eating away from the available `response` memory in the loop. This makes the program have *undefined behavior* and hanging is one possible outcome.

  One possible fix:

  ```c
  while (bufferSize > 1 && fgets(response, bufferSize, pFile) != NULL) {
      size_t len = strlen(response);
      response += len;
      bufferSize -= len;   // shrink what you tell fgets it can use
  }
  ```

  You could simplify it by using `fread` instead. The logic is the same but `fread` doesn't stop for newlines and returns how many items it read so you don't need to call `strlen` afterwards.

  ```cpp
  if (bufferSize--) {          // leave room for null terminator
      size_t len;
      while (bufferSize && (len = fread(response, 1, bufferSize, pFile)))     {
          response += len;
          bufferSize -= len;   // shrink what you tell fread it can use
      }
      *response = '\0';
  }
  ```
- The `command` simply don't finish. If `command` is waiting for something that never happens, it'll hang.
  Example: If `command` would execute this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script that waits for input from the user, it would just hang until the user had pressed <kbd>return</kbd>. You wouldn't see any output either since `fgets` is waiting for a newline that doesn't come (until *after* the user has pressed <kbd>return</kbd>).

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  echo -n "Enter: "
  read -r var
  ```

Comment: I agree. Makes me wonder why OP is using `fgets` in the first place; might as well just do a single `fread`.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Yes, or many `fread`s. The logic would be the same as above but will most probably require fewer system calls. The call to `strlen` wouldn't be needed either since `fread` returns the length.